# Comparing two split up lists of data in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

### The problem is as stated:

Find the discrepancies between two reports of object keys that are meant to be backups of each other.

---

The reports are broken up into multiple .csv files:

Report A could have 50 files, while Report B has 20, although both reports should contain the same amount of object keys.

The object keys within each report are in alpha-numeric order.

The sizes of the .csv files are unreliable, which is why we could see that 50/20 split mentioned above.

Assume the files are in order: If file1 from Report A contains a-c, then file2 will pickup at d.

Example of data (where each array represents what would be an individual file, and the containing array is the report as a whole):

```
 report1 =  [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7],
    [8, 9],
    [10],
 ]
 report2 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 ]
```

Keep in mind that this data is NOT stored in memory, I just have access to the file pointers associated with each array (file) that can iterate the forwards and not backwards.

---

The original algorithm was to treat them like two big lists, and change file readers when one ended, then iterate at the same time making comparisons. Assume the changing of files is already at play here. Pseudo-code:

```
while (not end of report1) and (not end of report2)
   if key1 < key2
      // key1 missing from report2
      move up reader1
   else if key2 < key1
      // key2 missing from report1
      move up reader2
   else
      // keys match and are in both reports
      move up reader1 and reader2
```

This was taking too slow. I need to work with billions of object keys.

I decided to parallelize the comparisons of the files individually, using the same comparison algorithm:

Report1's first file and Report2's first file are compared at the same time as both of their second files, etc.

Obviously this would cause a lot of false positive discrepancies, due to the differences in files sizes, but I run the compare algorithm again on ALL of the found discrepancies at the end of the processes.

This sped things up A LOT. However, 95% of the total discrepancies found during the multi processing, were false positives, again due to the terrible unreliability of these files sizes. Remember that 50/20 split? If we get to file21 from Report1, there is no file21 from Report2, so ALL of those items are marked as discrepancies.

The majority of the comparison work SHOULDN'T be done in the final comparison. It should be ideally done in the parallel process.

---

### Okay so now for my question:

What are some ways that I could go about parallelizing these comparisons? I would like to use as little memory as possible and significantly reduce that 95% false positive number.

Comment: 1) *each report are in alpha-numeric order* - I see only numbers there; 2) *This was taking too slow* - that means you've run an actual code not a pseudo-code, so do post the actual code

Comment: This is meant to be more of a conceptual based question. The code is complicated an not worth posting. I am not having problem with the actual source code. Just how to approach this in general.
The numbers are just used as an example. You could throw letters in there too if you wanted.